# Auto-generate sequence for custom object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom object named "Listing".

Fields:

> 1) Status  (New, Pending, Booked) - Picklist
>
> 2) Booking Number - Text Field

We want to autogenerate Booking Number whenever status is changed to Booked.

Booking Number should be in sequence (Alphanumeric i.e. BN-000091).

It should be generate only for booked status.

How can we do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest simply creating a native Auto Number field `Booking_Auto_Number__c` whose format is `BN-{000000}`, and do not place that field on the page layout. Then, add a new Text-type formula field with a formula something like this:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Booked"), Booking_Auto_Number__c, "")
```

Place the formula field on the page layout, and then you'll only see the auto number when the status is "Booked".

If you absolutely must have sequential numbers with no gaps in the sequence, you will need to write a trigger to populate this field, utilizing a Custom Setting to store the current highest auto number value. But if you do this, think carefully about how you plan to handle deleted records, records whose status changes a second time, and what happens when multiple users update Bookings at the same time. It's a lot of engineering for a very small requirement, when Salesforce native functionality will get you 90% of the way for free.

You can use a [`FOR UPDATE`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm) clause to serialize access to your Custom Setting. Ensure your trigger is bulkified and performant so that you avoid frequent issues with `QueryException` or `DMLException` from deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks, but we need autonumber populated in sequence. 
No matter what is the order of creation. There should not be any gap between sequence.

Comment: Is there any way to lock custom setting while updating a record with apex ? To ensure no any other update that time.

Comment: I've used the custom setting -> sequence number method before. I don't remember if they still iterate during Apex Test execution. You will want to make sure that your trigger does different behavior if a test is running when it iterates the "auto" number.

Comment: Great point, @DavidSchach - I *believe* instances created in a test context  are safe if you're not using a "real", native Auto Number, since Custom Settings are isolated in test context, while native Auto Numbers do increment.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Auto Number field type. Just use what Salesforce gives you.

[image: Data Type selection]